# Did CSS has second-letter pseudo element

Tags: css, pseudo-element

I'm using a CSS style for a letter to change a color of a first second third letter.

like this:

```
.header .logo h1 > a:first-letter {
  color: #f91ea5;
}
```

but I don't know how to change a color of second and third letter 
it's don't have a second-letter element.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think, you cannot use pseudo elements as `:second-letter` or `:third-letter`. It's by design.
But if it's realy necessary, then use JavaScript, for example: [this](http://codepen.io/FWeinb/pen/djuIx) or [this](http://css-tricks.com/a-call-for-nth-everything/).

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no selector for second or third letter, in [Selectors Level 3](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/) or even as planned in the [Selectors Level 4](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors4/) draft. (If there even will be such selectors, they will most probably follow the patter of `:nth-child(...)`.)

What you can do is to wrap the letters in text-level containers, e.g.

```
<a ...>A<span class=second>C</span><span class=third>M</span>E</a>
```

Then you can use normal class selectors like `.second`.