# HTML conditional styling in Anki Cards

Tags: html, anki

I'm making cards in Anki to teach my children phonics. I want to emphasize 'a' in word 'bad'.
[screen capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zaVzC.png)

How to use conditional styling to make 'a' to red color?

Comment: I think the answers to these two questions may help you out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17341670/change-color-of-one-character-in-a-text-box-html-css and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23189981/did-css-has-second-letter-pseudo-element